# Audio recording with AAC encoder?

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am recording audio through **MediaRecorder** and the problem is that:

when i use **AMR_NB** encoder, getDuration() return correct value but on the other hand when i use
**AAC** encoder it gives increased getDuration value.(i.e. if i record 5 sec audio it gives 40 sec and play for 40 sec)

code to record audio file

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);            
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);                       
recorder.setOutputFile(filePath); 
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

code to play recorded audio:

```
mp.setDataSource(audioPath);
mp.prepare();             
Log.e("duration of record"," " +mp.getDuration());                   
mp.start();
```

plaese provide some guidance..
thanks..

Comment: It just looks like the file recorded is of 40 seconds. Transfer it to a PC and see what is the actual duration.

Comment: How to do it without MediaRecorder? Let's say i already have raw inputstream.

Answer (score 0):

Check the AudioSampleRate, because AMR_NB only works at 8KHz but AAC can do up to 44,1KHz. You should work at the same sample rate always, or do a conversion/calculate the correct duration.

```
MediaRecoder.setAudioSamplingRate(frequency);
```